# Release build crashing after a successful build in android and iOS after changing appName for a react native project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, react-native, react-native-cli

Android release build crashing after changing app_name (strings.xml).
App is building and running successfully in DEBUG variant but failing with the below error in release varian both through CLI (`react-native run-android --variant release --deviceId XYZZ`) and through android-studio.

screenshot of logcat logs

[image].

Steps taken to resolve:

1. Clear gradle cache.
2. Remove node modules, yarn lock and reinstall modules
3. Invalidate cache and restart android studio.
4. Clear project cache in Android studio.
5. gradlew clean

Please note the DEBUG build is successfully running.

`"react": "16.8.3", "react-native": "0.59.4", gradle-5.4.1, buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3, compileSdkVersion = 28, targetSdkVersion = 28, supportLibVersion = "28.0.0", googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0""`

EDIT:
AppName in package.json and app.json and getMainComponentName() in MainActivity class all refer to the same name and AppRegistry is using the appName from app.json(project created using react-native init).

Comment: Please close all node process then build it again

Comment: Check the androidManifest file. `android:label="@string/app_name`

Comment: @hongdevelop Yes in my manifest it's being referred from strings.xml(        android:label="@string/app_name"). Also please note it's working in DEBUG and not in release variant

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari Killing node process and building again didn't help either. Even the most powerful tool full reboot didn't help either. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue to be not related to change in appName rather app unable to start because of issue in store.js implementation. 
`const middlewares = [thunk, __DEV__ ? logger : null];` Trying to apply a null middleware is the issue for app crashing on boot. But thanks to the friendly vague message `Application is not registered` which ruined most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your index.js and see the first argument to `AppRegistry.registerComponent()` this should be imported from `package.json`. Go there and change app name accordingly

Comment: registerComponent is referring to the appName from app.json file which is unchanged. 
@Max package,json, app.json, mainActivity getAppName also refer to the same name(XYZ). Also note while changing the app_name aka displayName(ABC) i have changed only strings.xml in android and bundle_display_name on iOS. Please correct me if i am still missing something here.